# How to check number inputs in the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to check if an input on my shell script was an alphabetic character or a character.
how can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by character? Almost every argument in bash is a character

Comment: I mean alphabetic characters

Comment: it's personal preference, but when I want to validate a string I personally use `egrep` to run regexp against it and check the return code.

Comment: example: `echo $string | egrep '^[0-9]+$'`

Comment: You can also use `awk` for this and there's probably some fancy bash syntax out there for it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really vague, so some guesswork here:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
if [[ -z "$input" || $input == *[^[:digit:]]* ]]; then
    echo "your input '$input' is not a number" >&2
    exit 1
fi
echo "congrats, '$input' is a number"
```

In bash, inside `[[...]]` the `==` operator is a [*pattern matching* operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b), so we're looking for any non-digit characters there.

Comment: your code snippet is clearer to me (once I read it properly) but it looks like it doesn't check for an empty string.

Comment: Right, it didn't. updated

Answer (score 1):

If your input is in $VAR....

```
if [ -z "${VAR//[0-9]/}" -a ! -z "$VAR" ]; then
  echo only has digits
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for an alphabetical character is just a matter of:

```
case $input in
  ([[:alpha:]]) echo one alpha character;;
  (*) echo 'non-alpha or not one character (or non-character)';;
esac
```

The character is decoded as per the locale's character set/encoding, and the locale is queried again to check if it's in the *alphabetical* character class.

Checking for `$input` being a character is trickier.

```
case $input in
  (?) echo one character
esac
```

Is meant to check for that. However, with most shells, that will also return true if `$input` contains one byte that doesn't form a valid character. To account for that you could do:

```
case $input in
  ([[:alpha:]]) echo one alpha character;;
  (?)
     n_chars=$(($(printf %s "$input" | wc -m)))
     if [ "$n_char" -eq 1 ]; then
       echo one character
     else
       echo one byte that is not a character
     fi;;
  ("") echo empty;;
  (*) echo anything else
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

While the others answers are great, here is a *one-liner* solution

```
grep -q '^[[:alnum:]]*$' <<< "$mybar" && success_command || failure_command
```

If you want to return do failure command on empty string, use the following

```
grep -q '^[[:alnum:]]\+$' <<< "$mybar" && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```